# Comparison string in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.software
(
    software_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    version text COLLATE pg_catalog."default", 
)
```

In that table I store software and their versions which I use in some projects and I check whenever they updated by comparing their version. I need to store the version informations as string because some versions contains strings like "1.0.1-beta".

I still couldn't find the best way to compare the strings. I use following (simplified) query:

```
    SELECT '1.2.3' < '1.2.4' -- true


    SELECT '1.2.3a' < '1.2.4B'
```

When i run following query:

```
select '3.0.0' > '26752' -- true

select '1.2.3a' < '1.2.3A' -- true

select 'i dont know' >= '2' --true
```

But 3.0.0 is smaller than 26752. 1.2.3a is (maybe) false, if I use lower() function I can solve it. How about **select '3.0.0' > '26752'** or the last query?

Comment: If you didn't have non-numeric parts, this would as easy as `select string_to_array('3.0.0','.')::int[] > string_to_array('26752','.')::int[]`

Comment: If you are okay to have a extension then check this [semver](https://pgxn.org/dist/semver/doc/semver.html)

Comment: I can't install semver because it gave me the error "semver.control not found". Then i copied all files from shared to main extension directory. no i'm getting semver not found.. i think have to also copy lib directory but cant find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed semver extension, which works great! thanks @arun

Answer (score 0):

In general, the best solution for that is to translate version numbers into something numerical.

The best I can offer you is an ICU collation for “natural comparison” (available from PostgreSQL v10 on):

```
CREATE COLLATION en_natural (
   provider = icu,
   locale = 'en-US-u-kn-true'
);

ALTER TABLE public.software
   ALTER version TYPE text COLLATE en_natural;
```

That will make a best effort.

Of course, `1.0.1` will still be less than `1.0.1-beta3`, as well as less than `1.0.1a`, because there is no built-in knowledge that “beta” is less than an empty string, while other strings are not.

Comment: Thanks, but according to semver standards 1.0.1 is bigger than 1.0.1-beta3.

Comment: Then you'll probably have to use the extension.